# JSON Service passing empty/null string parameter value

Tags: json, wcf

I have set of WCF services which allow JSON format for message exchange.

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", 
 ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
 RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
 UriTemplate = "SearchStores/{accountId}/{storeName}")]
public IList<Store> SearchStores(string accountId, string storeName)
```

How can I pass an empty/null storeName to the method?

If I using following url to invoke the method, i get 404 not found error.

```
servername:port/myservice/SearchStores/1/
```

Comment: The letters "null", without quotes, denote a null value in JSON.  Of course, whether that's accepted by whatever you're talking to is another matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify your template to use query string parameters instead.

```
UriTemplate = "SearchStores?accountId={accountId}&storeName={storeName}"
```

This way, `accountId` and `storeName` would be null if not specified in the query.  If only `storeName` is allowed to be null, you could of course leave `accountId` as is and build the `UriTemplate` with a query string parameter for `storeName`.

**EDIT**

If you are not allowed to use the query string, then you can use a default null value in your `UriTemplate` as described in the [MSDN UriTemplate documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675245.aspx).  In your case:

```
UriTemplate = "SearchStores/{accountId}/{storeName=null}
```

Note that once you use a default null value, all segments to the right must also have null default values.  For instance, this would be valid:

```
UriTemplate = "SearchStores/{accountId}/{storeName=null}/{someParam=null}
```

But this would not:

```
UriTemplate = "SearchStores/{accountId}/{storeName=null}/{someParam}
```

Comment: I cannot use query string notation. it has to be route data. is there a way to specify default (null/empty string) for storeName using route notation? thanks

Comment: @joblot - Updated my answer given your constraint.